# How to implement decorator Pattern with Autofac for the below scenario

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, autofac, decorator

I need to implement decorator pattern using Autofac.

I have two classes/services with their own implementation. Now based on a condition I need to be able to call either of the service class dynamically to get the data.

```
ServiceClassA : InterfaceA 
{
   // Method A
}

ServiceClassB : InterfaceB
{
  //Method B
}
```

Currently I have the Registered the ServiceClassA and ServiceClassB like below

```
builder.RegisterType<ServiceClassA>()
       .WithParameter( new resolvedParameter())
       .As<InterfaceA>()
       .InstancePerLifeTimeScope();

builder
       .RegisterType<ServiceClassB>()
       .As<InterfaceB>()
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

The ServiceClassA is called from within the controller (ControllerClass) like below

```
ControllerClass : Controller 
{
  private readonly InterfaceA _serviceClassA;
  public Controller(Interface serviceClassA)
  {
    _serviceClassA = serviceClassA;
  }

  public ActionResult Get()
  {
   var obj = _serviceClassA.MethodA();
  }
}
```

When the above call is made, based on a condition (date > 31st March 2020 ) the method B in ServiceClassB should be called. To achieve this our technical architect thinks decorator pattern with Autofac is the solution with little impact for the existing flow of the code.

So I made the below changes for the ServiceClassA registration

```
builder.RegisterType<ServiceClassA>()
           .WithParameter( new resolvedParameter())
           .Named<InterfaceA>("serviceClassA")
           .InstancePerLifeTimeScope();
 builder.RegisterDecorator<InterfaceA>(
            (c,serviceClassA) => ServiceDecorator(), 
            "serviceClassA");
```

after the above steps I am stuck, dont know where how to apply the condition. Checked a lot of answers on stackoverflow to find the solution not able to.

Comment: This is not really answer-worthy so here goes as a comment. If I were you, I would take a look at interceptors: https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/interceptors.html. You can have your interceptor contain the logic to decide which of the two methods should be called, or which one of the two services should be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The decorator pattern relies on both classes implementing the same Interface. Not as you described above. E. G.

```cs
public interface IProductRepository
{
  Product Get(int id);
}

public class ProductRepository : IProductRepository
{
  public Product Get(string id)
  {
    // logic to get product
  } 
}

public class LoggingProductRepository : IProductRepository
{
  private IProductRepository _productRepository;
  private ILog _logger;

  public LoggingProductRepository(IProductRepository productRepository, ILog logger) 
  {
    _productRepository = productRepository;
    _logger = logger;
  } 

  public Product Get(string id) 
  {
     _logger.Log("something");
     return _productRepository.Get(id);
  } 
}
```